# QMake message not printing

Tags: qt, qmake

All, I am attempting to work with a monolithic build system given to me by someone else (isn't that always the case?) and wanted to add some debug statements for myself.

The main `.pro` file uses a subdir template with the concept of:

```
SUBDIRS += durp-dir

durp-dir.file = Durp/durp.pro
```

When I add a `message("In Durp")` to `durp.pro` it never gets printed. I can't figure out what I'm missing. I'm using QT 4.8 ... Still examining the qmake documentation with no leads.

Comment: Try with simply `SUBDIRS += Durp/durp.pro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `qmake -r` instead of just `qmake`

Comment: Yes this was it, thank you very much. I'm confused though, it seemed like the Makefile was correct without the `-r` what does the `-r` option do? (I know it recursively goes the directories, but that's vague)

Comment: The -r tells qmake to immediately process all of the subdirs recursively. Otherwise this would happen lazily as part of the build process. So even without -r, I bet you'd see the messages in the subdir's .pro file during the build (i.e. after you typed make).